# Passenger error in Django cPanel web application

Tags: python, django, cpanel, passenger

Getting error when trying to deploy website.
Setup:
CloudLinux
Cpanel
Application Manager (Phusion Passenger) - Development = True
Python 3.8 venv
Django + Django Rest Framework - Debug = True

The Phusion Passenger(R) application server tried to start the web application. But the application itself (and not Passenger) encountered an internal error.

I have included the seetings.py & wsgi.py files for reference.

Error received:

```
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 369, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 76, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "/home2/fpicsnp/fpic_resources/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fpic_resources.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/fpicsnp/fpic_resources/fpic_resources/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

Settings.py file

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'b=+eif_^duy#xz6c1%*g%)7r4dl*$)o&3yo0$th_u+ntbz)vui'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['fpic.snpolytechnic.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'fpic_resources.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'fpic_resources.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'fpic_resources',
        'USER': 'fpicsnp_fpicadmin',
        'PASSWORD': 'FPICAdmin#MySQL',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[BASE_DIR + "/assets",]
STATIC_ROOT='/home2/fpicsnp/public_html/static'
MEDIA_ROOT='/home2/fpicsnp/public_html/media'
```

wsgi.py file

```
import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/home2/fpicsnp/virtualenv/fpic_resources/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages')


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'fpic_resources.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is still hard to debug your problem at this point.

1. Are you using the wsgi.py as your passenger_wsgi.py? There are some additional codes that you need to include in the passenger_wsgi.py to correct the POST request.
2. The passenger_wsgi.py should reside at the level of manage.py. The wsgi.py created by `startproject` command is different from the passenger_wsgi.py
3. If you are following the 2 Scoops of Django for multiple settings, you need to ensure that you are giving the right path to DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.
4. The DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and SECRET KEY should be an environment variables. See [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE).

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.